# Is there a UniData SQL equivalent to the UniQuery SAMPLE keyword?

Tags: sql, unidata

I'm using UniData 6. Is there a UniData SQL equivalent to the UniQuery SAMPLE keyword?

Using UniQuery, I've always been able to do:

```
SELECT CUST BY NAME SAMPLE 1
```

and it would give me the record with the first alphabetical name.

In UniData SQL, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
SELECT NAME FROM CUST ORDER BY NAME SAMPLE 1;
```

...or, as in other SQL databases...

```
SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM CUST ORDER BY NAME;
```

and get just the name of the the customer who's listed first alphabetically. Is there a keyword like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there does not appear to be a UniSQL equivalent to the UniQuery SAMPLE keyword.  UniSQL consists of a subset of ANSI [SQL-92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) standards, with some extensions to support multivalue.  However, ANSI SQL-92 does not contain a standard for limiting the result set returned from a query, which is why various DBMS have different syntax for doing so.

ANSI [SQL-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) added the [FETCH FIRST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Limiting_result_rows) clause which is the standard way of implementing a limit to the number of rows returned by a query.  It would require a pretty significant update to bring UniSQL up to recent standards since it is now 20+ years behind.  There doesn't seem to be significant enough demand in the user community to undertake that effort.

Depending on your file's schema, you may be able to apply a workaround.  If you are using an auto-incrementing key, you could use a syntax such as:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE @ID <= 10
```

The above query would be apply a de facto limit to the number of rows returned.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT will usually only apply to record IDs. If you want to list out attributes, try LIST: `LIST INVENTORY PROD_NAME PRICE QTY SAMPLE` for instance will return the first 10 product names, prices and quantities.

Comment: Hello, Jesse. Welcome to Stack Overflow.
The `SELECT` and `LIST` commands you're referring to are UNIQUERY commands, not UniData SQL commands. My question is specifically about a solution involving UniData SQL.